# How to prevent ant from creating zips with different hash?

Tags: java, ant, zip

I have a build script that creates .zip files created with Ant from Gradle:

```
ant.zip(destfile: targetFile) {
   fileset(dir: tempLocation) {
        include(name: "*/**")
   }
}
```

(basically it calls the Java Ant library and thats it)
My problem is that when I zip the same folder twice the hashes of the two .zip files differ. For our build pipeline I need the 2 zips to have the same hash if they contain the same files (the files inside are exactly the same). Anyone knows how to do this?

heres an example:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9186429/573.zip
vs
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9186429/574.zip

EDIT:
After some investigation it turns out that zip files store the modification timestamp of files. Can the Ant zip tool alter/remove this?

Comment: does it help if you set `filesonly` to true? Otherwise Ant may create entries for directories with the current time as creation time under certain circumstances.

Comment: no, the issue is that ant.zip stores the files modification date with them, after looking at the source of Ant you cant omit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by setting the modification date to a hardcoded constant of all files that I zip:

```
file.setLastModified(Constants.defaultModifiedTime);
...
ant.zip {
...
```